# Select 1field from database in php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have a problem with this code.

I want select lang from `Users` table and if was `fa` send a message to user with telegram bot can u help me plz

```
// Create connection
$sconn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($sconn->connect_error) {
    die("</br>Connection failed: " . $sconn->connect_error);
}
else{
    echo "</br>Connected successfully</br></br></br>";

} 
$sconn->query("set names utf8mb4");
$ssql = "SELECT lang FROM Users WHERE user_id=$user_id";
$result = $sconn->query($ssql);


if($ssql == "fa"){
       var_dump(bot('sendMessage',[
        'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
        'text'=>"test",
        ]));
}
$sconn->close();
```

Comment: Shouldn't  if($ssql == actually be if( $result->lang == ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if($ssql == "fa"){
```

You've used $ssql earlier in the script to store your SQL - checking for "fa" will never return true.

You need to use mysqli_fetch_assoc to get the data - there's a short example at https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp